Intercept another object while matching velocity in 2D
There are dozens of solutions online for finding how to intercept an accelerating object, etc. But I have a more stringent requirement for interception.
Suppose object I can accelerate and is trying to catch object T which moves in a straight line at constant $v_t$. $I$ has initial velocity $v_i$, and it must perform the interception with just two straight-line accelerations, $\vec{a_a}$ and $\vec{a_d}$, for times $t_a$ and $t_d$, with given magnitude $a$ in unknown directions $\theta_a$ and $\theta_d$.
At the interception point, $\Delta r$, the two velocities must also match. This gives us two vector equations, or 4 equations with the 4 unknowns, $t_a, t_d, \theta_a, \theta_d$, by splitting the vectors into components.
$$ \vec{v_i} + t_a\vec{a_a} + t_d\vec{a_d} - \vec{v_t} = 0  \tag{1} $$
$$ (t_a + t_d)\vec{v_i} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{a_a}t_a^2 + \vec{a_a}t_at_d + \frac{1}{2}\vec{a_d}t_d^2 - \Delta r = 0 \tag{2} $$
This is painfully nonlinear; MATLAB can't find a solution in this form, but I am wondering if there is some way to transform it. I even noticed that if you call $(2)$ as $F$, then $(1)$ is $\partial F/\partial t_d - \vec{v_t}$, so you can solve an ODE to get an equation with an $\exp(-t_d)$ in it, but I don't know if that's useful or even correct.
Any other hints on how to approach this?

@idon'tknowwhatiamdoing Thank you for your answer; I upvoted it. I was going to leave it open for a bit in the hope someone knows a more direct way to solve it. The problem with Newton's method is the need for a good initial guess, but otherwise it does work well here. Or can you show that no better solution exists?
